# Why do I get a "configure: error: Could not compile basic X program." error when trying to compile Spidermonkey?

Tags: compiling

I am trying to install spidermonkey on 11.10. However I am having many compile issues.

Most recently I have received this error, but I cannot understand exactly what the error is.

```
checking whether C compiler supports -fprofile-generate... yes
checking whether C++ compiler has -pedantic long long bug... no
checking for correct overload resolution with const and templates... no
checking what kind of list files are supported by the linker... linkerscript
checking for glib-2.0 >= 1.3.7 gobject-2.0... yes
checking GLIB_CFLAGS... -pthread -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-   gnu/glib-2.0/include  
checking GLIB_LIBS... -pthread -lgobject-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0  
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for sys/int_types.h... no
checking for iwlib.h... yes
checking for posix_fallocate... yes
configure: error: Could not compile basic X program.
renshaw@renshaw-TravelMate-5740G:~/spidermonkey$
```

I was trying to follow from an answer on [stackoverflow - install spidermonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656904/best-way-to-get-spidermonkey-js-on-ubuntu-11-04). I am not having much success.

Is that error above resolvable?

Answer (score 1):

You should install the `-dev` package, which provides the necessary  [header files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_file):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libxt-dev
```